# flutter background image carousel

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and working on developing my flutter coding skills. I want to display 3 background images in a  carousel while other texts and button remain same on the screen. in the below code, image carousel is working properly **but my *Get Started button* and *other texts* not displaying at all.** what should I do for correct this issue. appreciate your help on this.

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.leanBack);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          CarouselSlider(
            items: [
              //1st Image of Slider
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/person1.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(5, 65, 196, 0.19),
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
              //2nd Image of Slider
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/person2.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(5, 65, 196, 0.19),
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
              //3rd Image of Slider
              Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned.fill(
                      child: Opacity(
                        opacity: 0.8,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/person3.png',
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(5, 65, 196, 0.19),
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],

            //Slider Container properties
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: 810.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              autoPlay: true,
              aspectRatio: 16 / 16,
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enableInfiniteScroll: true,
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              viewportFraction: 1,
            ),
          ),


          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, bottom: 230),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                child: Text('Meet \nYour Doctor\nHere',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      height: 1.2,
                      fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                      fontSize: 35,
                      color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ))),
          ),


          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 26),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text('DOCTOR',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: 'Dubai',
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ))),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
            child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 320,
                  height: 65,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'Get Started',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                          backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                              Color(0xff05ABA3)),
                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                              RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                            RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                            ),
                          ))),
                )),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
              child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    height: 5,
                    width: 120,
                  ))),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include an image that you are trying to archive? and Texts are showing on scroll because you are using `ListView` on body.

Answer (score 0):

you can set image in background using BoxDecoration in container-

```
Container(
  height: 120.0,
  width: 120.0,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: AssetImage(
          'imagename'),
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ),
    shape: BoxShape.circle,
  ),
)
```

Comment: its not help for solve my question. kindly please read the question

Answer (score 0):

On your `Scaffold`'s `body:` you are using `ListView`. You can still find those widgets by scrolling down.

For your case, you like to have text and button widgets over the UI.

You need to replace `ListView` with `Stack` on body.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Stack( // this
    children: [
      CarouselSlider
```

More about [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) and [`ListView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html).